# How to connect to Neo4j server with blueprints api?

Tags: java, neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop

I installed Tinkerpop Gremlin plugin to my Neo4j server.

I want to connect to it from Java and execute Gremlin queries and I'm following this guide: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Using-Gremlin-through-Java

I get stuck right at the first line:

```
Graph g = ... // a reference to a Blueprints graph
```

What should I give here to instantiate `g`?

I have working `Cypher` example, and I tried instantiating `g` as RestAPIFacade. But it wont work that way.

EDIT:
I see now that Neo4jGraph is the implementation I was missing (I missed the dependency blueprints-neo4j-graph).

```
Graph g = new Neo4jGraph(GraphDatabaseService)
```

I'm still missing information on how to use GraphDatabaseService.

Comment: Something like this ? Graph graph = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph(); (scrolling down...)

Comment: Thats for making a new graph. I'm trying to connect to a server. I see that, the question I should be asking is how to open a connection with GraphDatabaseService and only then you use Graph Class

Comment: Any luck with that since then? I'm on the exact same problem...

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question and edit correctly you want to know how to get a handle on an instance of `GraphDatabaseService` so that you can pass it in the constructor for `Neo4jGraph`?

You can do this with:

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "path/to/neo4j/data" );
```

where `path/to/neo4j/data` is the path to the existing Neo4j database. More info [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html)

Comment: This is for an embedded database. I'm using Neo4j in remote mode, and I would like to try the Gremlin plugin. What I'm missing is, how to connect to http://93.xx.xx.x:7474/tp/gremlin/execute , and how to execute a simple query.